# Override google-java-format with spotless-maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, formatting, continuous-integration

I'm looking to implement a pre-commit automatic formatter for my team because the code is a bit all over the place. I like spotless and the google style but a sticking point seems to be 4-space indents, whereas it's currently outputting 2-space indents.

Is there a way to override this value via pom.xml, either on spotless side or the google side?

Answer (score 7):

As instructed in Github issue comments here: https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/420

You can solve this in Gradle build with:

```
indentWithTabs(2)
indentWithSpaces(4)
```

For Maven the same code would be:

```
    <java>
        <googleJavaFormat>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <style>GOOGLE</style>
        </googleJavaFormat>
        <indent>
            <tabs>true</tabs>
            <spacesPerTab>2</spacesPerTab>
        </indent>
        <indent>
            <spaces>true</spaces>
            <spacesPerTab>4</spacesPerTab>
        </indent>
    </java>
```

Answer (score 5):

Google java format is not configurable by design: https://github.com/google/google-java-format/pull/57#issuecomment-233450426

> There is no configurability as to the formatter's algorithm for formatting. This is a deliberate design decision to unify our code formatting on a single format.

Also see: https://github.com/google/google-java-format/wiki/FAQ#i-just-need-to-configure-it-a-bit-differently-how

Answer (score 4):

A quick update: the spotless plugin can now be configured to do what you want.  I.e. google-java-format with 4 spaces.

As mentioned in the docs: https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-maven
you can now use the AOSP 'style' which does what you need.

```
      <googleJavaFormat>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <style>AOSP</style>
      </googleJavaFormat>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other answer, I tried to indent with `Tabs(1)` and `Spaces(2)`. It also worked.

```
spotless {
    java {
        googleJavaFormat("1.7")
        indentWithTabs(1)
        indentWithSpaces(2)
    }
}
```